# Python 3 remove empty list

Tags: python

I am finding a line from a text that has 10 lines.

```
desc    = re.findall(r'@description (.*)', comment.strip())
```

What happens is it returns the `@description` but it also has 9 empty lists.

```
print(desc)
```

returns:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
['the desc is here']
[]
```

So how do I get rid of those empty `[]` and make `desc=['the desc is here']`?

---

**update**

I tried list filter and still the same return

The comment contains:

```
/**
 * @param string username   required    the username of the registering user 
 * @param string password   required
 * @param string first_name required
 * @param string last_name  required
 * @param string email      required
 * @package authentication
 * @info user registration
 * @description register a new user into the groupjump platform
 */
```

---

**update**

comment is a full string, so I split it like this so I can read line by line

```
comments = route['comment']
comments = list(filter(None, comments.split('\n')))
```

---

**actual code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

routes = []
description = ''
with open('troutes.php', 'r') as f:
    current_comment = ''
    in_comment = False
    for line in f:
        line = line.lstrip()
        if line.startswith('/**'):
            in_comment = True

        if in_comment:
            current_comment += line

        if line.startswith('*/'):
            in_comment = False

        if line.startswith('Route::'):
            matches = re.search(r"Route::([A-Z]+)\('(.*)', '(.*)'\);", line)
            groups = matches.groups()
            routes.append({
                'comment': current_comment,
                'method': groups[0],
                'path': groups[1],
                'handler': groups[2],
            });
            current_comment = '' # reset the comment

for route in routes:

  # get comments
  comments = route['comment']
  comments = list(filter(None, comments.split('\n')))

  for comment in comments:
    params  = re.findall(r'@param (.*)', comment.strip())
    object  = re.findall(r'@package (.*)', comment.strip())
    info    = re.findall(r'@info (.*)', comment.strip())
    desc    = re.search(r'@description (.*)', comment.strip())

    print(comment[15:])
```

data being read:

```
<?php
/**
 * @param string username   required    the username of the registering user 
 * @param string password   required
 * @param string first_name required
 * @param string last_name  required
 * @param string email      required
 * @package authentication
 * @info user registration
 * @description register a new user into the groupjump platform
 */
Route::POST('v3/register', 'UserController@Register');

/**
 * @param string username   required    the username of the registering user 
 * @param string password   required
 */
Route::GET('v3/login', 'UserController@login');
```

Comment: What is there in `comment`?

Comment: I get only, `['register a new user into the groupjump platform']`

Comment: [works on my machine](http://ideone.com/pKeoD2). Please provide a short, self contained, runnable example that exhibits your problem.

Comment: does filter(len, desc) still work in python3  ?

Comment: why a regexp? To extract the text from the line containing `@description`, just do `data[15:]`

Comment: @thefourtheye yup, thats the only data i need. but my code returns empty lists if the regex cant find the data on that line. how do I restructure my code to only find the description if im looking for it?

Comment: No restructuring is required; the code you provided gives the result you want. Perhaps there is a difference between the code you are running, and the code you have shown us.

Comment: @majimboo Please show your actual code which produces that output. Otherwise this question might be closed for no SSCCE.

Comment: updated with actualy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're matching the pattern line by line. Why don't you match against the whole comment?

```
>>> comment = '''/**
...  * @param string username   required    the username of the registering user
...  * @param string password   required
...  * @param string first_name required
...  * @param string last_name  required
...  * @param string email      required
...  * @package authentication
...  * @info user registration
...  * @description register a new user into the groupjump platform
...  */'''
>>>
>>> import re
>>> desc = re.findall(r'@description (.*)', comment)
>>> desc
['register a new user into the groupjump platform']
```

Comment: Its not about displaying really. Its just about making the variable `desc = the desc`

Comment: Oh, I just realized what you said. Thanks it works now.

Answer (score 1):

A condition for a single list is just:

```
if desc:
    print(desc)
```

It is a shorthand version of:

```
if len(desc) > 0:
    print(desc)
```

For a list of lists it's:

```
desc = [d for d in desc if d]
```

To get only the string do this:

```
if desc:
    print(desc[0])
```

Comment: Nope, the other list is still there

Answer (score 0):

You can filter list with an empty string from a list of lists with a list comprehension:

```
desc = re.findall(r'@description (.*)', comment.strip())
desc = [d for d in desc if len(d[0]) > 0]
```

Another solution is to print the element only if the first element contains something:

```
desc = re.findall(r'@description (.*)', comment.strip())
for d in desc:
     if len(d) > 0 and d[0]:  # check if there's a first element and if this element isn't empty
           print d
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your code to work you need to work on a single string, if you have 10 lines do like this:

```
joined = "\n".join(lines)
for i in re.findall(r'@description (.*)', joined):
    print (i)
```